# Sitecore calendar module not displaying in week view

Tags: module, calendar, sitecore

Have implemented the Sitecore (6.5 rev.120427) calendar module (2.4.0 rev.110602) on our staff intranet.

Everything works great except for when switching from 'Day' or 'Month' view to 'Week' view in IE (All other browsers work fine). When trying to switch to 'Week' view, the calender section that should show times and events doesn't appear at all.

When I go directly to a page featuring a 'Week' view it will display, but as soon as I click the 'switch to week view' button, the section will disappear.

Anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in IE7 and IE9 in "Comparability View". It would appear that a height of `0px` is being applied to the week view - probably as an attempt to apply HasLayout to the element for IE6 compatibility.

My recommendation would be to contact Sitecore Support and let them know about this. I sounds like a easy fix that they can supply a fix for.

In the meantime, you can override the height setting with the following CSS rule:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.weekGrid tr > td > div { height: auto !important; /* use a fixed height in px if you need to preserve scrolling */ }
</style>
```